# Получить имя пользователя C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, файловая-система, path

Нужно создать папку в /home/user в Linux, для этого нужно в коде прописать путь. Как получить имя этого user-а?

Comment: команда терминала```whoami``` даст Вам имя юзера

Comment: @HegoJune Наверно я непонятно объяснил. Задача подставлять имя пользователя на разных компьютерах. Оно же у каждого свое. Как в C++ это реализовывается(в коде а не в терминале)

Comment: Это не сильно простая задача как кажется на первый взгляд.

Comment: Кстати, здесь в ответах ни одного решения нет, только горстка весьма частных случаев...

Comment: Если речь идет о текущем пользователе, то ваш вопрос - классическая XY-проблема. Вам не нужно "получить имя этого user-а", вам нужно получить путь к home-директории текущего пользователя.

Comment: @0andriy, вы бы лучше вместо этой неконструктивной критики - взяли бы да и написали ответ. К чему эти интриги? Хотим правильный ответ!

Comment: @vp_arth, кто хочет реально научиться, будет искать сам, я лишь даю подсказки. Ведь SO про это? Готовые решения — это про другое. Заметьте, автор вопроса пальцем об палец не ударил, чтобы попытаться сделать что-то самостоятельно.

Comment: SO — в первую очередь «база знаний» Автор вопроса — лишь один из тысяч потребителей ответа.

Comment: @0andriy  Как же я должен по вашему решить проблему не зная даже основ C++. Вы говрите так, будето  я работаю программистом и задачи, которые мне ставят на работе я пишу сюда. НЕТ. Я учусь. Читать документацию, не зная где искать ответ...не продуктивно. Этот сервис предназначен, чтобы помогать другим НАУЧИТЬСЯ программировать. Если все будут искать ответы самостоятельно, то StackOwerflow можно закрыть. Не хотите отвечать, не засоряйте своими комментами сайт. Есть ответ - отвечайте! Ведете себя напыщенно! Если вы такой "бывалый", то подыщите себе сервис достоный вас, где нет таких лентяев

Comment: @0andriy этой строчки `std::getenv("HOME")` было вполне достаточно. Если ударить пальцем о палец по вашему написать код за меня, то вы не правы. Код есть и написал  его сам и как использовать эту строку разобрался тоже сам. Не хватает только одной строчки.

Comment: @vp_arth, так правильный путь подсказан maint ниже.

Comment: Значит я не понял [коммент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862976/Получить-имя-пользователя-c-linux?noredirect=1#comment1394589_862976) выше

Comment: @МаксимДонец, если вы не знаете основ C++ (впрочем, они тут и не нужны — это же чистый Си!), то может с этого стоит начинать? Вопросы задавать тоже надо уметь. За вас вашу работу никто делать не будет, так что это тоже учёба, а учитель из меня никакой, поэтому я ответы редко пишу.

Comment: @vp_arth, так это не готовое решение по вопросу же! Но мысль, изложенная там, верная (за исключением упоминания */etc/passwd*, речь всё-таки о ресурсах, а не конкретном файле). Если пользователь найден, то у него либо будет домашний каталог, либо нет (не помню навскидку что в этом случае выдаёт API), если есть, то надо смотреть можно ли в него записать (homeless пользователи), ну и так далее... P.S. И конечно, надо откуда-то взять идентификатор пользователя ещё, обычно только имя известно или около того. Последний ответ от VTT, например, только для самого себя.

Comment: @0andriy по моему мы говорим на разных языках. В каком месте я прошу сделать все за меня?

Comment: @МаксимДонец, в вопросе. Почитайте на досуге http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html, и хорошего настроения, удачи вам!

Comment: @0andriy так вы просто провокатор..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv

Имя пользователя, скорее всего, можно узнать как `std::getenv("USER")`, хотя зачем, если `std::getenv("HOME")` сразу даст домашний путь.

Comment: а какой инклюд нужен?

Comment: Ну там написано вверху страницы: Defined in header <cstdlib>

Comment: Пользователь может быть без домашнего каталога. Ваши действия?

Comment: @0andriy Водки выпить. О чем-нибудь вечном поразмышлять. Сыграть какую-нибудь балладу.

Comment: Отлично! Но проблему это не решит ;)

Comment: Ещё может быть случай, что переменная окружения специально выставлена не туда, куда надо, родительским процессом. В общем, учите, детки, Unix.

Comment: @0andriy Разумеется. Может быть вообще так, что никак домашний путь не узнать, а если узнать, то ничего с этим знанием не сделать. Где-то ведь надо остановиться, перебирая варианты.

Comment: @0andriy А часто бывает, что нет домашнего каталога? Я думал при установке он сам создается. Там же всякие папки лежат для системы, вроде как, важные? И как же вы решили бы эту проблему?

Answer (score 3):

Функция getpwuid() возвращает указатель на структуру, содержащую поля строки из файла /etc/passwd для записи, совпадающей с идентификатором пользователя uid.

Структура passwd определена в файле  следующим образом:

```
struct passwd {
    char    *pw_name;       /* имя пользователя */
    char    *pw_passwd;     /* пароль пользователя */
    uid_t   pw_uid;         /* id пользователя */
    gid_t   pw_gid;         /* id группы */
    char    *pw_gecos;      /* настоящее имя */
    char    *pw_dir;        /* домашний каталог */
    char    *pw_shell;      /* программа-оболочка */
};
```

Comment: Прям и пароль сразу выдаст?

Comment: зашифрованный иногда. А может и пусто. От системы зависит и от пользователя, точнее прав пользователя. Если память не изменяет

Comment: Пользователя может и не быть в */etc/passwd*.

Comment: Существующего юзера может не быть? Да ладно?

Comment: @vp_arth, ага. Это же Unix.

Comment: Кстати, Windows NT тоже унаследовала эту особенность. Так что и там так бывает.

Comment: @0andriy, вы же говорите про возможность изменить /etc/passwd в рамках сессии? Или есть другие возможности?

Answer (score 0):

Это можно реализовать в два шага: получение идентификатора пользователя затем получение информации о пользователе по идентификатору:

```
errno = 0;
auto const uid{::geteuid()};
if(0 != errno)
{
    // handle error
}
if(NO_UID == uid)
{
    // handle error
}
errno = 0;
auto const p_info{::getpwuid(uid)};
if(0 != errno)
{
    // handle error
}
if(nullptr == p_info)
{
    // handle error
}
auto const psz_user_name{p_info->pw_name};
if(nullptr == psz_user_name)
{
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Не хватает ещё шага для выяснения пути к домашним каталогам.